# Simpler function to reset classes, add to target class 'active', and filter map based on different parameters

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm working on a map project where I built my own UI. Part of it is a navigation where you can filter the map by clicking a div button in a column floating at the edge of the map. It works perfectly fine, currently, but it is overly complicated and will be a major issue to explain how to add new buttons as the data expands.

The gist is that it first defines a variable as the button id, and on click resets all the classes to a default set, except for the button which is clicked gains the class 'active', and executes a function which sets filtering based on an assigned id in the dataset or return true for All.

The way I have it, which is functional but extremely cluttered

Edit: I've made a few changes that substantially reduce the lines, but I still don't know how to combine multiple similar copies of these into a single function

```
//define variable to point to a specific button

var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation').children;
var all = document.getElementById('filter-all');
....
//[Currently] nine additional variables of nearly the same thing (now just for selecting the button pressed)

//Show all
all.onclick = function() {
    navigation.className = navigation.className.replace(new RegExp('\b' + active + '\b'),'');
    this.className += ' active'; //for some reason this doesn't actually add the space
    map.featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        // Returning true for all markers shows everything.
        return true;
    });
    map.fitBounds(map.featureLayer.getBounds());
    return false;
};
....
//Followed by nine nearly identical functions that just reset classes, and sets filtering parameters
```

I know there is a way to combine the functions to do the same thing without so much bulk, but my search is so far fruitless.

Comment: Well as a first step you could use a framework like f.e. jQuery – that’ll make the event handling much nicer, and also the setting/removing/toggling of element classes is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, that was going to be my next step if I couldn't figure out a loop or something to combine the functions, but that may prove difficult while dealing with elements with unique ids and possibly varying outputs